# Generate multiple files from single file based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning python, trying to use it for one of my manual activity which i perform using excel filter operator.

Every month i receive a file, i put that csv into an excel then applying filter create a new file for value in carrier field and share that with respective carrier.

here is some sample data from my csv. I have shown only 2 carriers here but i have more than 13 values,

```
carrier,type,count
DTH,a,123
DTH,b,3123
DTH,c,41341
DTH,d,13411
BLUEDART,a,12123
BLUEDART,b,31231
BLUEDART,c,411
BLUEDART,d,11
```

Expected output

DTH.csv

```
carrier,type,count
DTH,a,123
DTH,b,3123
DTH,c,41341
DTH,d,13411
```

BLUEDART.csv

```
carrier,type,count
BLUEDART,a,12123
BLUEDART,b,31231
BLUEDART,c,411
BLUEDART,d,11
```

Any help or just guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use a dict. The key should be the carrier name and the value is a list of lines that belongs to this carrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

carriers_csv_path = r"C:\Users\Bluetab\PycharmProjects\utils\csvGeneratorStack\csvCarriers.csv"
carrier_df = pd.read_csv(carriers_csv_path)
grouped_by_carrier = carrier_df.groupby(["carrier"])
unique_keys = carrier_df['carrier'].unique()


for unique_key in unique_keys:
    grouped_by_carrier.get_group(unique_key).to_csv("./" + unique_key + ".csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

Hope it helps.

Tomas

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard library of Python only:

```
import csv

def write_output(header_row, carrier_name, c_rows):
    print("writing output for "+carrier_name)
    with open("c:\\tmp\\"+carrier_name+".csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
                outwriter = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",")
                outwriter.writerow(header_row)
                for outrow in c_rows:
                    outwriter.writerow(outrow)

with open("c:\\tmp\\carrier.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    first_row = True
    header_row = None
    groups = {}

    for row in creader:
        if first_row:
            header_row = row
            first_row = False
        else:
            if not row[0] in groups:
                groups[row[0]] = [row]
            else:
                groups[row[0]].append(row)

    for gr in groups:
        write_output(header_row, gr, groups[gr])
```